# Is there a logging plugin for Eclipse with functionality like Apache Chainsaw?

Tags: eclipse, logging, eclipse-plugin, apache-chainsaw

I'm searching for a eclipse plugin that allows me to view log files like Apache Chainsaw does. In addition I'm hoping that such a plugin would allow me to click on a given logging message and automatically jump to the line of source code where the logging message was generated.

Is such a plugin available for Eclipse?

Comment: If there's not, then you've just given me a great idea for my next project :)

Comment: @Sandman: Yes it would be a nice and useful tool :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly like Apache Chainsaw but still have a look at these:

1. http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/logviewer/
2. [Log file viewer for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802409/log-file-viewer-for-eclipse)
3. http://sourceforge.net/projects/logfiletools/
4. http://workingdeveloper.net/node/1

If you want use standard eclipse log viewer in your application then have a look at this link: http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/08/17/eclipse-rcp-error-view/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the open-source http://sourceforge.net/projects/ganymede/. It is supposed to support log level coloring, filtering and some other Chainsaw-like features. It's an Eclipse plugin and ships with a .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I found another one:

- [Logback Console Plugin for
  Eclipse](http://logback.qos.ch/consolePlugin.html)

But I guess it doesn't work with Log4j as Apache Chainsaw does.