# Can I log into separate Eclipse consoles with logback or something?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, console, logback

Is it possible to configure a logger from a Java library (like logback) so that it logs into separate windows in Eclipse?

I want to distinguish library printouts from my program printouts.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5964135/422353

Answer (score 0):

If the external library uses a different logging framework you can set it up to output to a file and then configure your loggers to output to a different file. Admittedly, it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: Eclipse will ask me whether I wish to reload changed file from disk. I can't press "yes" all the time. I need window to update constantly itself like console window does.

Comment: Well, maybe something like [this viewer] (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/logviewer) could help. Disclaimer: have not used it.